# How to avoid the mouseover event from the parent element when the mouse is exiting both parent and child if the parent has a border

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: What I want is for the nested div to not be moved when the mouse leaves both it and the parent div. I'm pretty sure it **is** currently moving  because the border somehow extends the parent further out than the nested div. I'd like to keep the border.

Like someone once said, [a demo is worth a 1000 words](http://jsfiddle.net/a1cqLvtm/4/).

I have a div nested in a div

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div>Check me out</div>
</div>
```

That has some styling

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
}
```

And some accompanying Javascript

```
var navBar = document.querySelector('div.parent');
var navItems = navBar.querySelector('div');
var moveNav = false;
var overItems = false;

navBar.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { moveNav = false; });
navItems.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { overItems = true; });
navItems.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { overItems = false; });
navBar.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { moveNav = !overItems && true; });
navBar.addEventListener('mousemove', moveToMouse);
function moveToMouse(e) {
    if(!moveNav)
        return;
    navItems.style.left = (e.offsetX - Math.floor((e.offsetX+navItems.offsetWidth)/navBar.offsetWidth) * (e.offsetX + navItems.offsetWidth - navBar.offsetWidth + 10)) + 'px'
}
```

The purpose is to keep some part of the child div under the mouse while the mouse is inside the `.parent` div.*

What I'd like to know is **how to make the child div not be moved as the mouse exits the `.parent` div?**

In other words, I want it to act like it does in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxqe21j1/). The difference between the fiddles is that the first has a border around `.parent` and the second is borderless.

And of course, I've noticed that child div jerks around instead of moving smoothly. Suggestions as to how to avoid that are welcome but not expected.

*if there's some better way to accomplish that, please do point it out**

**don't say "use jQuery"

Comment: I am really not sure what you meant, but.. I added css property- ` box-sizing:border-box;` is this what you wanted?

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Pretty vague altogether.

Comment: Does this jquery method sound like it will do the trick for you: 
`event.stopPropagation()` https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/?

Comment: @Shikkediel i'm having trouble finding the words... on the first demo, when you mouse out of the `Check me out` "going up" div, the mouseover event for the parent fires. If you look at the second demo, it doesn't. I'm pretty sure that it fires on the first demo because the parent has a border and doesn't happen on the second demo because the parent has no border. I'm trying to see how to avoid the mouseover event firing but only when the mouse leaves the child from the top or bottom.

Comment: `I've noticed that child div jerks around instead of moving smoothly`. Replace `mouseover` with `mousemove` in your last event handler: https://jsfiddle.net/yna9ozyx/

Comment: @KhanhTO doesn't answer **the** question but does answer the question. thanks:)

Comment: @mark i don't think so. I think the event fires on the parent because the parent's border extends past the child. So after the mouse leaves the child it then leaves the parent. (i'm thinking the fact that the event doesn't fire if there is no border is not a good thing)

Comment: Conclusion - can't be done in this setup. Use box-shadow or outline instead (they're not actual content)... most often one isn't even mousing over the child at all so there's nothing to make any distinction.

Comment: @Shikkediel lol, i'm worried you're right. Outline will do what I actually want. Thanks for sticking with my vague question!

Comment: Wrecked my brain for at least half an hour, lol. :-p

Answer (score 0):

In the example of the div with border, I used mouseenter event instead of mouseover and it seems to be working the way you want it.

```
navBar.addEventListener('mouseenter', moveToMouse);
```

Comment: Thanks and you're right but, I'd really like to use what Khanh suggested so that the nested div will follow the mouse around so this won't work for me. Updated question to reflect that